# wget mirror into my git direcotry

Tags: directory, wget

I want to `wget --mirror` into a specified directory.
I can use `-P <PATH>` but it still makes a subdirectory with the website name.

My Git directory name is `buddhadust`
The website is http://buddhadust.net

So when I do a test it downloads into the specified directory, but makes a whole new folder called `buddhadust.net`

Here is the command I use, but I'm still getting the default folder creation with the name of the website inside the specified directory "buddhadust"

```
wget -P buddhadust --mirror -N --no-parent http://buddhadust.net
```

There are two reasons why I want to do this.
1.  Copying files is a nightmare and often the files are set with new dates.
2.  If I download directly into the GIT, I don't have to copy files and save a step

Comment: Would the `--cut-dirs` option (See `man wget`) help?

Comment: I don't think this will work.. -nH might do the trick, but the wget seems to stop short for checking for new material.  Without this option and deleting index.html from the buddhadust.net dir., it checks the whole website

Comment: I can make a directory fresh direcotry buddhadust and it will work with -nH if I run the wget inside that directory.  Now just need to figure out how to have it still cycle through to know which files are new which is another issue.  So I might just answer the question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can go into the git directory and create a terminal in that directory.  Then I can use -nH flag.  The problem is that it does not cycle through all of the files to see if there are new files added which is another [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/155743/how-to-refresh-an-online-website-mirror-created-with-wget-mirror).  However, this issue is solved.

Need to delete index.html in order for it to cycle through the files.

```
wget -nH --mirror  http://buddhadust.net
```